# XmlReader - Self-closing element does not fire a EndElement event?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0, xmlreader

I am using XmlReader in .NET to parse an XML file using a loop:

```
while (xml.Read()) {
   switch xml.NodeType {
     case XmlNodeType.Element:
      //Do something
     case XmlNodeType.Text:
      //Do something
     case XmlNodeType.EndElement:  
      //Do something
   }
}
```

I was wondering if it was normal that the following XML code does not produce some EndElement nodes? Please note the missing space before the /> but I don't think that's the problem.

```
<date month="November" year="2001"/>
<zone name="xml"/>
```

Is there a different NodeType or property to indicate a self-closing element?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No, you check it by looking at [XmlReader.IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.isemptyelement.aspx).

In the docs for that property:

> A corresponding EndElement node is not
>   generated for empty elements.

Comment: How would I tell the difference between `<element />` and `<element></element>` when my current `NodeType` is `StartElement`? `IsEmptyElement` is `true` for both scenarios.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: You'd see whether an `EndElement` node is present, basically... I don't know any way of doing it immediately when you're on the `StartElement`.

Comment: Thanks--turns out I may have been wrong about `IsEmptyElement` being true in those cases. I've been staring at this output for too long :-)