# Reading in XML (that uses shorthand tags) with C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlReader - Self-closing element does not fire a EndElement event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241336/xmlreader-self-closing-element-does-not-fire-a-endelement-event)

A group of us are busy working on a university portfolio for C#... one of the applications we have to code is a weather app... it must fetch XML coding from a website and then display the necessary weather info, e.g. precipitation, temp etc.

We have found multiple ways of doing this on the web but cannot find a way to deal with shorthand tags. The website we have to use has the following xml coding:

```
<symbol var="01d" name="Fair" number="1"/> <precipitation value="0"/> 
<!-- Valid at 2012-10-10T14:00:00 -->
<windDirection name="South" code="S" deg="182.4"/> 
<windSpeed name="Moderate breeze"     mps="5.9"/> 
<temperature value="17" unit="celsius"/>     
<pressure value="1021.3" unit="hPa"/>
```

i.e. it generally uses the shorthand method for tags....

Can anyone help us with C# code that can recognize the tag element and collect the attribute information from it?

The closest we have is this:

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("weather.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
```

But this only works for XML with longhand tags....
Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read attributes from tag with (from msdn):

```
      while (reader.Read())
            {
...
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Attributes of <" + reader.Name + ">");
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" {0}={1}", reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    }
                    // Move the reader back to the element node.
                    reader.MoveToElement();
                }
...
```

Comment: Encouraging someone to parse xml attributes in this fashion is stupid.

Comment: Well, maybe he does not know exactly what attribute he wants but just want to pick all key=value pairs and insert those data to db? But, yes I agree, in most cases XElement is right way to do

Comment: Also, I think this is good answer about what to choose (XDocument or XMLReader) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096564/xmltextreader-vs-xdocument

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The "shorthand" you describe is generally termed XML attributes.</strike> Don't use an XmlReader. There are better tools for the job. Assuming a structure more like:

```
<someRoot>
    <symbol var="01d" name="Fair" number="1"/> <precipitation value="0"/> 
    <!-- Valid at 2012-10-10T14:00:00 -->
    <windDirection name="South" code="S" deg="182.4"/> 
    <windSpeed name="Moderate breeze"     mps="5.9"/> 
    <temperature value="17" unit="celsius"/>     
    <pressure value="1021.3" unit="hPa"/>
</someRoot>
```

You could easily parse attributes out of this as follows:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(someXmlString);
string someAttrValue = doc.Root.Element("symbol").Attribute("var").Value;
```

Comment: No, the "shorthand" refers to the self-closing tags.

Comment: Hah! It wasn't clear and I misunderstood. Everything else still stands.

Comment: +1 for XDocument. Very convinient.