# XmlTextReader & XmlNodeTypes

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I'm working with the XmlTextReader and use a switch to determine which operations I want to do depening on the XmlNodeType.

```
switch(xmlTextReader.NodeType)
{
    case XmlNodeType.Element
    {
        ...
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

and so on...

Now I have a small problem. As far as I know,

```
XmlNodeType.Element
```

matches any node with the following syntax

```
<xxx>
```

and

```
XmlNodeType.EndElement
```

matches

```
</xxx>
```

But what XmlNodeType matches

```
<xxx/>
```

?

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241336/xmlreader-self-closing-element-does-not-fire-a-endelement-event